# How to establish two-way audio communication with Nest doorbell?

Tags: webrtc, nest, audio-streaming, ip-camera, sdp

I could stream video and audio from a Nest doorbell (battery) using the Google Smart Device Management API.  That involves creating a WebRTC connection using the GenerateWebRtcStream call to exchange SDP offers and answers.

However, GenerateWebRtcStream only allow one-way audio (i.e., setting "a=recvonly") in the offer.  Any attempt to send an offer with "a=sendrecv" results in "invalid argument" error.

Obviously, the steps to establish two-way audio is undocumented.  Has anyone had better luck?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Traits description it says (cf. [description](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#request_4)):

> Required: The audio setting in the offerSdp for this command must be set to a=recvonly (receive only).

There is no other command to set up the stream - therefore, it is not possible to establish two-way audio (not yet?!).